# Legend not generating

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to build a legend to a calendar view graph using d3 js [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmpUx.png)

but i'm trying to build a legend to it like the kind of shown in the pic

[image]

but i'm not able to generate this

here's my code to generated calender view map

```
var Comparison_Type_Max = d3.max(inputData, function(d) { return d.value; });

        var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return  (d[0].value ); })
        .map(inputData);

         var margin = { top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 10, left: 60 }, 
         width = $(dom_element_to_append_to).parent().width() - margin.left - margin.right,         
         cellSize = Math.floor(width/52), 
         height = cellSize * 7 + margin.top + margin.bottom ,
         week_days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'],
         month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
         $rootScope.defaultWidth = width;
         $rootScope.cellSize = cellSize;
         var day = d3.time.format("%w"),
         week = d3.time.format("%U"),
         percent = d3.format(".1%"),
         format = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d"),
         legendElementWidth = cellSize * 2,
         buckets = 9,
         parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

         var color = d3.scale.linear().range(colorRange)
         .domain([0, 1]);
         var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
        .range(colorRange);

         var svg = d3.select(dom_element_to_append_to).selectAll("svg")
         .data(d3.range(year, year+1))
         .enter().append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .attr("data-height", '0.5678')
         .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
         .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        //.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
        console.log("1");

        svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-38," + cellSize * 3.5 + ")rotate(-90)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

        for (var i=0; i<7; i++)
        {    
            svg.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-5," + cellSize*(i+1) + ")")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dy", "-.25em")
            .text(function(d) { return week_days[i]; }); 
        }

        var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "day")
        .attr("width", cellSize)
        .attr("height", cellSize)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return week(d) * cellSize; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize; })
        .attr("fill",'#fff')
        .datum(format);
        console.log("2");



      /*  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend");
        //.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (((i+1) * cellSize*4.33)) + ",0)"; });

        legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", cellSize / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(Math.sqrt(data[d] / Comparison_Type_Max )); });


        legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height + cellSize);
        */


        var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });

        legend.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend");

        legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", cellSize / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(Math.sqrt(data[i] / Comparison_Type_Max )); });

        legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height + cellSize);

        legend.exit().remove();

        svg.selectAll(".month")
        .data(function(d) { return d3.time.months(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "month")
        .attr("id", function(d,i){ return month[i] + "" + varID })
        .attr("d", monthPath);





        console.log("4");

        var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function(d) {
            var year = d/10000;
            year = Math.floor(year);
            var month = d/100;
            month = Math.floor(month % 100);
            var day = d % 100;
            if(day<10) day = "0" + day;
            if(month < 10) month = "0" + month;

            if(isCurrency)
             return  "<div><span>Date:</span> <span style='color:white'>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</span></div>" +
       "<div><span>Value:</span> <span style='color:white'><span>&#8377</span>" + d3.format(",")(data[d]) + "</span></div>";
       else
             return  "<div><span>Date:</span> <span style='color:white'>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</span></div>" +
       "<div><span>Value:</span> <span style='color:white'>" + d3.format(",")(data[d]) + "</span></div>"; 

 });

        console.log("5");

        svg.call(tip);

        console.log("6");

        rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
        .on("click", function(d){
            console.log(d);
            var year = d/10000;
            year = Math.floor(year);
            var monthInt = d/100;
            console.log(dom_element_to_append_to);
            var val,id;
            if(dom_element_to_append_to=='.sms-yearheatmap-container-negative')
             val = 0;
       else if (dom_element_to_append_to=='.sms-yearheatmap-container-positive')
             val = 1;
       else val = 2;

       monthInt = Math.floor(monthInt % 100);
       for (var itr = 0; itr<12; ++itr) {
             id = month[itr] + "" + varID;
             $('#' + id).css("z-index",0);
             $('#' + id).css("stroke","#000");
             $('#' + id).css("stroke-width", "2.5px");
       }
       id = month[monthInt-1] + "" + varID;
       $('#' + id).css("stroke","blue");
       $('#' + id).css("position","relative");
       $('#' + id).css("z-index",1000);
       $('#' + id).css("stroke-width", "4.5px");
       console.log("year " + year + " month" + monthInt);
       $rootScope.loadDayHourHeatGraph(year, monthInt , val, isCurrency);
 })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(Math.sqrt(data[d] / Comparison_Type_Max )); })
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
        /*.attr("data-title", function(d) { return "value : "+Math.round(data[d])});   
        $("rect").tooltip({container: 'body', html: true, placement:'top'}); */
      /*  $("rect").on("click", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
      });*/

      function numberWithCommas(x) {
         x = x.toString();
         var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
         while (pattern.test(x))
          x = x.replace(pattern, "$1,$2");
    return x;
```

it is generting the graph correctly but my legend is not generating with it
here's the code of legend which i wrote above

```
 var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
        .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });

        legend.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend");

        legend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
        .attr("height", cellSize / 2)
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(Math.sqrt(data[i] / Comparison_Type_Max )); });

        legend.append("text")
        .attr("class", "mono")
        .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
        .attr("y", height + cellSize);

        legend.exit().remove();
```

i don't want to use the colorscale variable instead i want to generate the legend according to the color variable defined in the main code, the colorscale variable is not used anywhere in the code but only in the legend just for a  start, the whole calender view graph is generated using the the colorscheme provided by the color variable

Comment: Why the `legend.exit().remove();`?!

Comment: actually i'm a newbie to d3 js so i took help from some other websites , there was a code of dayhour heatmap which had the same legend, so i did  try to implement the same as shown in the image

Comment: Well, most of us are newbies when it comes to d3 :)! I asked about this because remove is used to remove the data and since I cannot run your script, it could be the reason you don't see your legend. Also, try positioning your legend with `.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")` or something similar.